# laptop hangs when disconnecting hdmi monitor

Tags: hdmi, radeon, intel, monitor

I'm on ubuntu 18.04, and my laptop is a dell inspiron 15 5000 series with a intel core i7-7500u cpu and a radeon graphics card: VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445].

I usually use a second monitor connected trough the hdmi port and every time I disconnect it, my laptop froze and I have to hard reboot...

I did a search, but most problems I found are when connecting a monitor.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you determined if the device actually "hangs" in the sense that the system has stopped running instead of simply the graphics failing? A common test is to press CTRL+ALT+F2 or F3, F4, etc. to switch between "sessions"

Comment: yes, I did test all common key combinations and there is no response

Comment: I suggest when the system comes back online you run look at `/var/log/syslog` for errors. Note that the most recent log entries will likely be related to the system booting, so you'll have to go back a bit to find the system hanging. Also note it may be possible no such log entries exist depending on how it's hanging.

Comment: ok, i did what you suggested, but I have no idea on what to look. Here is the log: https://yadi.sk/i/lUVQ2XwiBLloiQ. Btw, I didn't mention that the only thing that is responsive is the mouse movements, not its clicks...

Comment: Here I let only those around the time of the error: https://yadi.sk/i/5cHb_HlNtoRB0g